# remove selected values from array for criteria - mongodb + python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB:

```
words_collection

_id : 615b4b923c04c57ee5f8b054
words : Array
    0 : "house"
    1 : "dog"
letters : "a"

_id : 615b4bd93c04c57ee5f8b055
words : Array
    0 : "house"
letters : "b"

_id : 615b4bf33c04c57ee5f8b056
words: Array
    0 : "house"
    1 : "dog"
    2 : "cat"
letters : "c"
```

and in the Python I have two arrays : `words_to_delete=['house','dog']`, `letters_filter=['a','c']`

I would like to remove all items from array `words` in my collections that exist in `words_to_delete` list in Python, but only for those records where `letters` is in `letters_filter` list.

I think I could filter all records in my collection where `letters in letters_filer` and for selected `_ids` I could loop over `words` array and delete values that exist in `words_to_delete` list.
But this is Python way that might not be too efficient when I have 300k records in my collection.
Is there any MongoDb way to do it? More efficient?

Comment: Yes efficiently, you can delete the words from the array (this would be an update operation on the collection documents), with a filter on the letters. See the `$pull` and `$pullAll` array update operators in the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: OK, $pull and $pullAll allow me to delete elements from words array but how do I filter by letters? I found findAndModify(document) but also stuck.

Comment: An update method has a _filter_ and an _update_. $pull is a an update operator and is used within the update. The filter is where you check for the characters. You can use other update methods also, `updateOne`, `updateMany`, etc.

Comment: @prasad_ I appreciate your comments, but I'm just starting mongodb I really have no clue how to do it. Spend 2 evenings doing some experiments but it doesn't work. can you guide me a bit more?

Comment: for example: updated = words_collection.update_many(
    {"letters": {"$in" : [letters_filter] },
    { "$pull": { "words": { "$in": [ words_to_delete] }}})

Comment: Try without the `[ ]` (brackets) for the variables `letters_filte` and `words_to_delete`, in your code. Also, refer the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

Comment: I've tried this:  updated = words_collection.update_many({"letters": {"$in" : letters_filter }, { "$pull": { "words": { "$in": words_to_delete}}}) and doesn't work. Any more hints?